# How to get the option from CMFCPropertyGridProperty ComboBox?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to get option from ComboBox of `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` class

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty* pShpType_S = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("shpType_S"), shpType_S, _T("shpType_S"));

pShpType_S->AddOption(_T("POINT"));
pShpType_S->AddOption(_T("LINE"));
pShpType_S->AddOption(_T("BOX"));
pShpType_S->AddOption(_T("CIRCLE"));
pShpType_S->AddOption(_T("SPHERE"));
pShpType_S->AddOption(_T("MESH"));
pShpType_S->AllowEdit(FALSE);
```

Comment: New here? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use:

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty* pProperty = ...;
COleVariant vProperty = pProperty->GetValue();
if (vProperty.vt == VT_BSTR)
{
    CString strValue = vProperty.bstrVal;

    // If you also want the index
    bool bFound = false;
    int iNumOptions = pProperty->GetOptionCount();
    for (int iOption = 0; iOption < iNumOptions; iOption++)
    {
        if (strValue.CollateNoCase(pProperty->GetOption(iOption)) == 0)
        {
            // Match!
            bFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // iOption has the index value.
}
```

Lookup:

- [`CMFCPropertyGridProperty::GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-variant-t?view=vs-2019)
- [`CMFCPropertyGridProperty::GetOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-variant-t?view=vs-2019)
- [`CMFCPropertyGridProperty::GetOptionCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-variant-t?view=vs-2019)
- [`COleVariant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-variant-t?view=vs-2019)

The variant can contain several different types of values and you have to check the `.vt` member. For combo properties the value will be a text string, so you check for `[VT_BSTR][1]`.

The actual definition of `[CMFCPropertyGridProperty::GetValue][1]` is:

`virtual const _variant_t& GetValue() const;`

So you can also use [`_variant_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-variant-t?view=vs-2019) instead of `COleVariant`. But I use the latter.